# Leetcode 875: Koko Eating Bananas

Tags: java, binary-search

[Leetcode 875: Koko Eating Bananas](https://leetcode.com/problems/koko-eating-bananas/description/)

> Koko loves to eat bananas. There are n piles of bananas, the ith pile has piles[i] bananas. The guards have gone and will come back in h hours.
>
> Koko can decide her bananas-per-hour eating speed of k. Each hour, she chooses some pile of bananas and eats k bananas from that pile. If the pile has less than k bananas, she eats all of them instead and will not eat any more bananas during this hour.
>
> Koko likes to eat slowly but still wants to finish eating all the bananas before the guards return.
>
> Return the minimum integer k such that she can eat all the bananas within h hours.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: piles = [3,6,7,11], h = 8
> Output: 4
>
> Example 2:
>
> Input: piles = [30,11,23,4,20], h = 5
> Output: 30
>
> Example 3:
>
> Input: piles = [30,11,23,4,20], h = 6
> Output: 23

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Solution {
    public int minEatingSpeed(int[] piles, int h) {
        Arrays.sort(piles);

        int j = 0;
        int high = piles[piles.length-1];
      int i = 0;
      int k;
      outerLoop1:
        for( k = piles[0]; k <= high; k++) {
            while (j <= h && i < piles.length) {
                if (piles[i] > 0) {
                    piles[i] = piles[i] - k;
                }
                j++;
                i++;
                if (i == piles.length) {
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
            outerLoop:
            if (j == h) {
                int f = 0;
                while (f < piles.length) {
                    if (piles[i] > 0) {
                        break outerLoop;
                    } else {
                        f++;
                    }
                    
                }
                break outerLoop1;
            }
        }
        return k;
    }
}
```

I know that I was supposed to solve this using binary search but I did a different approach.

I run a for loop starting from the lowest value of k, i.e. of the lowest val in piles and go upto the highest, returning k at just the moment when everything in the pile is 0 or 1 (after repeated subtraction of k from it). If that isn't the case, I increment k and try again. From what I understand, break outerLoop gets out of the if statement and k is incremented. Whereas break outerLoop1 gets out of the very outer for loop of k and k is returned cause I found the value of k I needed.

What's wrong in my logic here?

I don't need a solution for this problem but just clarification on what exactly is wrong with my specific version of code and what tweaks I can make to fix it, approaching it the way I am right now.

Comment: *I know that I was supposed to solve this using binary search* How on earth do you know that? What are you searching for with binary search?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Binary search on the value of `k`. This is a fairly template problem.

Comment: piles = [ 2, 2 ], h = 4. Expected output: k = 1. Your algorithm searches k in the range from 2 through 2, so will not find the correct minimal value.

Answer (score 2):

> I run a for loop starting from the lowest value of k, i.e. of the lowest val in piles

Why is the minimum possible of k the lowest value in piles? Take the example: `piles={8};h=8`. Here, the minimum is 1, but your algorithm will never check that case because it starts checking at 8.